# Jquery need to append with just one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to append a div after click. But the problem is when i click the button the more then one jquery code appending again it again it again.

It should work like when you click .box then append `.fast_icon` div second click .append not append again because there is appended `.fast_icon`

Plase Attantion, The jquery code should work like this.

When you click `.box` div the jquery code see the `data-id` ,
    HTML

```
<div class="box" id="box1" data-id="1"></di> 

var ID = $(this).attr("data-id");
```

and checking  `.is-active` for same id `$(".ic"+ID).hasClass("is-active");`

If there is no `is-active` class then append `<div class="fast_icon"></div>`

Now here is my problem.

When you second click the `.box` div the code appending again `<div class="fast_icon"></div>`  but no need this because we clicked before same ID, we appended it in same ID.

I have to try it like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("click", ".box", function(e) {
    var ID = $(this).attr("data-id"); 
    //$(".fast_icon_answer").removeclass("is-active"); 
    if (!$(".ic"+ID).hasClass("is-active")) {
          setTimeout(function() {
        $(".ic" + ID).addClass("is-active");
      }, 10);
      $(".ic" + ID).append(
        '<div class="fast_icon"></div>'
      );
        } else {
          $(".fast_icon_answer").removeClass("is-active");
      $(".fast_icon").remove();
        }
  });
  $(document).bind( "mouseup touchend", function(e){
     var container = $('.is-active');
       if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
         $(".fast_icon_answer").removeClass("is-active");
         $(".fast_icon").remove();
        }
    }); 
});
```

Here is the **[DEMO](https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/WYyPrg)** from codepen.io

Comment: You can just use `.one` instead of `.on`, to make sure the handler only fires the first time

Comment: @RobinZigmond Your answer maybe is correct but it is bad for me because if i use your answer then the div can not append other `$(".ic"+ID)` after other clicks.

Comment: Why don't you use .html instead of .append. That way it will always replace it and will only append one div.

Comment: @RobinZigmond: sorry they bought it back. I remember they deprecating it. Will remove my comment.

Comment: can use  `$('body').off().on('click', '.box', function(e) {`

Comment: @joyBlanks His answer is not deprecated but not a solution for me.

Comment: why the settimeout?

Comment: @joyBlanks Because if i remove it then css cubic-benzier doesn't worked.

Comment: what if you add to ontransitionend event. There is an event like that I can't remember

Comment: SInce this is happening while your class didn't get the is-active class added/removed another request came in. Try using promises or have that ontransitionend listener to clear out future requests coming in while your animation is pending

Comment: what is the idea of `bind("mouseup touchend", ...)` ?

Comment: @NedkoDimitrov Click outside of .box then remove appended `.fast_icon` and remove `.is-active` class

Comment: with the second event you're removing all `.fast_icon` no matter what and `if (!$(".ic" + ID).hasClass("is-active")) ` is always false

Comment: @NedkoDimitrov Yes, but if i not use `bind("mouseup touched", ...)` then the appended div not remove after click somewhere.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly needs to be the end result. Could you clarify your question for me?

Comment: @NedkoDimitrov I need: When you click the `.box` then `.fast_icon` div will append in clicked `$(".ic" + ID)` . When you click again same `.box` then `.fast_icon` appending again in `$(".ic" + ID)` i don't want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the `if (!$(".ic" + ID).hasClass("is-active"))` condition in `.unbind(...)` to `!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0)`

if I understand you correctly, this should be what your need

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("click", ".box", function(e) {
    var ID = $(this).attr("data-id");
    //$(".fast_icon_answer").removeclass("is-active");
    if (!$(".ic" + ID).hasClass("is-active")) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".ic" + ID).addClass("is-active");
      }, 10);
      $(".ic" + ID).append('<div class="fast_icon"></div>');
    }
  });
  $(document).bind("mouseup touchend", function(e) {
    var container = $(".is-active");
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('box') || 
       !$(e.target).find('.fast_icon').length) {
      $(".fast_icon_answer").removeClass("is-active");
      $(".fast_icon").remove();
    }
  });
});
```

**Update**

Removed the else block in the `.box` click event

Comment: I have added more details in question can you read it please. Thanks for your answer also.

Comment: @Azzo did you test my answer? Let me know what is wrong so I can fix it

Comment: it is removing the appendded div after second click, it should stay appended div. When user click other side (no .box div) then appended div sould be remove.

Comment: @Azzo fixed that by removing the else block in the first event handler. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just replace js code with bellow code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("click", ".box", function(e) {
    var ID = $(this).attr("data-id");
    //$(".fast_icon_answer").removeclass("is-active");
    if (!$(".ic" + ID).hasClass("is-active")) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".ic" + ID).addClass("is-active");
      }, 10);
      $(".ic" + ID).append('<div class="fast_icon"></div>');
    } else {
     // $(".fast_icon_answer").removeClass("is-active");
     // $(".fast_icon").remove();
    }
  });
  $(document).unbind("mouseup touchend", function(e) {
    var container = $(".is-active");
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $(".fast_icon_answer").removeClass("is-active");
      $(".fast_icon").remove();
    }
  });
});
```